# a question about $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

Let $F_1 = \sigma(\{1\}),\dots, F_{n+1} = \sigma(F_n,\{n+1\})$ where $\sigma(A)$ means a $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$.

Then we have that $A_n=\{2n\}\in F_{2n}$
and $F_{2n}\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n$.
I want to ask why $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\not\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = 2\mathbb{N}$, the set of all even positive integers.

Assume $2\mathbb{N} \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$. This means there exists $j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2\mathbb{N} \in F_j$.

But, $$F_j \subseteq \mathcal{P}\left(\{1, \ldots, j\}\right)$$ This is a contradiction, since $2\mathbb{N} \not\subseteq \{1, \ldots, j\}$.

**Edit:**

If it is not entirely clear, we can prove by induction that $F_n \subseteq \mathcal{P}\left(\{1, \ldots, n\}\right)$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$:

For $n = 1$ we have:

$$F_1 = \sigma(\{1\}) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\} = \mathcal{P}(\{1\})$$

Assume that for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $F_n \subseteq \mathcal{P}\left(\{1, \ldots, n\}\right)$.

\begin{align}F_{n+1} &= \sigma(F_n \cup \{\{n+1\}\}) \\
&\subseteq \sigma\big(\mathcal{P}\left(\{1, \ldots, n\}\right) \cup \{\{n+1\}\}\big) \\
&\subseteq \sigma\big(\mathcal{P}\left(\{1, \ldots, n+1\}\right)\big) \\
&= \mathcal{P}\left(\{1, \ldots, n+1\}\right)
\end{align}